# Where to put ssl certificates when trying to connect to a remote database using psycopg2?

Tags: python, postgresql, psycopg2

I have created a Google PostgreSQL instance and I'm trying to operate it from a remote webserver, I have whitelisted the IP and turned on SSL-only mode. I created client certificates, but I'm clueless as to where to put them or how to reference them. I can't find anything about it online.

Any help would be appreciated

My psycopg2 connect statement looks like this and gives me an error saying it needs client certificates:

```
conn = psycopg2.connect(
            user="postgres",
            password="password",
            host="{IP_ADDRESS}",
            port="5432",
            database="testdb",
            sslmode="require",
}
```

Comment: Please add a [mcve] to illustrate what you'e got, what you are doing and what you are getting.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I figured it out myself, I got some instructions on how to connect with psql and that also applied to psycopg2.

Google instructed me I could connect through psql with this terminal command:

```
  psql "sslmode=verify-ca sslrootcert=server-ca.pem \
      sslcert=client-cert.pem sslkey=client-key.pem \
      hostaddr={IP_ADDRESS} \
      port=5432 \
      user=postgres dbname=postgres"
```

So I edited my connect function to add these keys:

```
sslrootcert=server-ca.pem
sslcert=client-cert.pem
sslkey=client-key.pem
```

Make sure to run

```
$ chmod 0600 client-key.pem
```

Or it won't work

Answer (score 2):

Since you have created the client certificates to connect to your instance using SSL, there must be three things to look for :

- A **server certificate** saved as *server-ca.pem*.
- A **client public key certificate** saved as *client-cert.pem*.
- A **client private key** saved as *client-key.pem*.

Depending on which tool you use to connect, these three items are specified in different ways. For example, when connecting using psql command-line client, these three files are the values for the **sslrootcert**, **sslcert**, and **sslkey** parameters in the psql connection string.

Here's some steps if you need more detail  [Connecting psql client using public IP](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/postgres/connect-admin-ip#connect)